# XSS why \n must be replaced by \n<br>

Tags: xss

I came across the following xss fix. The old code was:

```
this.commentText = new Text(Sanitizer.sanitizeForHtml(commentText.getValue()));
```

The xss fix code is:

```
String sanitizedText = Sanitizer.sanitizeForHtml(commentText.getValue()).replace("\n", "\n<br>");
```

Can you please clarify to me how `\n` can be used in XSS? and how replacing it with `\n<br>` will solve the problem?

Comment: Well, an explanation come to my mind replacing `\n` to `<br>` but I can't figure out why it shoud be replace by `\n<br>`

Comment: @Xavier59 it might be a mistake from the code author though. If you can post your explanation that may be helpful.

Comment: Which sanitizer is being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is not meant as a protection against XSS and there is no common context where it would do.**

Instead, the authors solve the problem that the newline character (`\n`) does not display a new line in HTML, so they add the `<br>` tag to enforce a visible line break.

The authors of the code even explain it in a comment themselves [here](https://github.com/TEAMMATES/teammates/blob/master/src/main/java/teammates/common/datatransfer/FeedbackResponseCommentAttributes.java#L195):

```
//replacing "\n" with "\n<br>" here is to make comment text support displaying breakline
String sanitizedText = Sanitizer.sanitizeForHtml(commentText.getValue()).replace("\n", "\n<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the dev want to output user input in a javascript variable.

If the user input with `\n` it will render as

```
var input = " hey
there"
```

Which in a `<script>` will render as an error and will cause it to be not executed because your string is not terminated !
Instead, replacing `\n` with `<br>` will result to the very correct `var input = "hey<br />"`

Comment: how this protects from XSS?

Comment: uhhm... the code in the question replaces **\n** with **\n<br>**, so there is still a line break in it.

Comment: @Lukas See comments on question ;)

Comment: @Xavier59 Ah, I see!